# symfony2 persist with ManyToOne

Tags: php, symfony, mapping

Trying to persist an object, but the field profiel_id with a mapping relation is not being saved. The rest of the object is, weird enough.

```
$fotos = new Fotos();
$fotos->setProfielId($this->profielId);
$fotos->setNaam($file->name);
$fotos->setAanmaakDatum(time());
$fotos->setWijzigingDatum(time());
$fotos->setProfielfoto(0);       
// Save the object
$this->em->persist($fotos);
$this->em->flush();
```

fotos.xml

```
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-   mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Klik\CoreBundle\Entity\Fotos" table="fotos">
<indexes>
  <index name="profiel_id" columns="profiel_id"/>
</indexes>
<id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
  <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
</id>
<field name="profielId" type="integer" column="profiel_id" length="11" nullable="true"/>    
<field name="naam" type="string" column="naam" length="255" nullable="true"/>  
<field name="profielfoto" type="boolean" column="profielfoto" nullable="true"/>

<field name="aanmaakDatum" type="integer" column="aanmaak_datum" nullable="true"/>
<field name="wijzigingDatum" type="integer" column="wijziging_datum" nullable="true"/>
<field name="wijzigingGebruikerId" type="integer" column="wijziging_gebruiker_id" nullable="true"/>
<!-- many-to-one field="profiel" target-entity="Klik\CoreBundle\Entity\Profiel" / -->

<many-to-one field="profiel" target-entity="Klik\CoreBundle\Entity\Profiel" inversed-by="fotos" >
  <join-column name="profiel_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
</many-to-one>

  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

When I remove the many-to-one declaration all is fine, profiel_id is saved, but other things break on other places which I don't want.

Here is part of my profiel.xml

```
 <one-to-many field="fotos" target-entity="Klik\CoreBundle\Entity\Fotos"  mapped-by="profiel" />
```

Comment: You should add the profile to the photo, not set the id.. Ie `$fotos->setProfile($this->profile)`, note this should contain the actual profile object - not just an id.

Comment: Thats it, thanks a lot! Would like to flag it as accepted or something but I do not have enough permissions unfortunately.

Comment: @Bart, In `ManyToOne` join you need to pass object in setter function instead of id.